# How to add subrows in a gt table in R

Tags: r

I would like that the following table can have more lines per each of the sector in the first column:

This is how it looks right now:

[image]

I use the following code:

```
tablesectortop <- gt(dftablesector)|>
    fmt_percent(
      decimals = 1
    )|>
    cols_label(
      newname = md("Sector"),
      "1980" = md("1980-1990"),
      "1990" = md("1991-2001"),
      "2000" = md("2002-2008"),
      "2020" = md("2009-2020"),
      Average_total_pct = md("**Whole Period**")
    ) |>
    tab_header(
      title = md("**1980-2020 Sectors' share in Top-10% Acquirers**"),
      subtitle = md("Ranked by average of whole period (last column in bold)")
    )|>
    tab_source_note(source_note = "Source: Compustat")|>
    tab_style(
      style = cell_text(weight = "bold"),
      locations = cells_body(
        columns = Average_total_pct,
        rows = Average_total_pct < 100
      )
```

But I would like it to look like this:

[image]